# Vuejs - Primevue - Display the property of an array of object in a Datatable Column

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, primevue

I'm new to Primevue, Here is my code :

### Vue File

```
    <!-- users here is an array of User object -->
    <DataTable :value="users" :rows="10" :paginator="true">
      <Column field="username" header="Username" :sortable="true"></Column>
      <Column field="email" header="Email" :sortable="true"></Column>
      <Column field="role.name" header="Role" :sortable="true"></Column>
      <Column field="cars" header="Cars" :sortable="true">
      </Column>
    </DataTable>
```

Here is what is inside a user object :

```json
    User {
      username: 'test',
      email: 'test@junk.com',
      id: 1,
      role: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Admin',
        description: 'Admin user',
      },
      cars: [ [Object], [Object] ]
    },
```

Currently `cars` property **contain** :

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Subaru BRZ"
  },
  {
     "id": 2,
     "title": "Lotus Evora GT"
  }
]
```

It's a very simple object. My goal is to display the cars **title for a user**, in the same column and on the same row (*field "cars"*) using **Primevue Datatable and Column**.

### EDIT

#### Solution

Here is the Datatable modified :

```
<DataTable :value="users" :rows="10" :paginator="true">
      <Column field="username" header="Username" :sortable="true"></Column>
      <Column field="email" header="Email" :sortable="true"></Column>
      <Column field="role.name" header="Role" :sortable="true"></Column>
      <Column field="cars" header="Cars" :sortable="true">
          <template #body="slotProps">
            <span v-for="car in slotProps.data.cars">{{car.title}}</span>
          </template>
      </Column>
    </DataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the `<template>` inside `<Column>` component? :)

Seems there is a nice explanation in the docs in the Templating section: https://primevue.org/datatable/#template

Hope it will help.